# Center Text Over Image While Keeping Column Alignment

Tags: html, css

I am using this syntax to create two columns left column aligned left, right column aligned right.  The syntax works perfect!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  html {height:100%;}
  body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
  #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%;z-index:-1; height:100%;}
  #content {position:relative; z-index:1;}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.wrap {
  width: 1060px;
  height:auto;
  margin: auto;
   text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
.text_over_image {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  color:#fff;
  height:100px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="bg">
<img src="C:Image1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="1stDay" />
</div>
<div>
  <span style="float: left;">
    <font size="30" color="red">Text1</font><br>    
    <img src="C:\1.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
  </span>
  <span style="float: right;">
    <font size="30" color="red">Text2</font><br>    
    <img src="C:\2.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
  </span>
</div>
<div style="height: 650px;"></div>
<div>
  <span style="float: left; clear:both">
    <font size="30" color="red">Text3</font><br>    
    <img src="C:\3.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
  </span>
    <span style="float: right;">
    <font size="30" color="red">Text4</font><br>    
    <img src="C:\t.jpg" alt="" style="width:425px;height:500px;">
  </span>
</div>
<div style="height: 650px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see omitting the call to `.wrap` in the syntax below.  If I add the call to `.wrap` in my `<div>` tags column structure is destroyed.

How can I center text over my images and maintain the column structure that is created with the call to `#bg?`

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). You can flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the image with an `<img>` tag.  Add it via CSS `background` property with keywords `no-repeat center center fixed` like below.

```
background: url(../media/pic.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
```